# Jenkins custom pipeline and how to add property to be set in jenkinsfile

Tags: jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I'm trying to create a custom pipeline with groovy but I can't find anywhere on the web where it is discussed how to add a property that can be set in the jenkinsfile.  I'm trying to add a curl command but need the URL to be set in the jenkinsfile because it will be different for each build.

Can anyone explain how that should be done or links where it has been discussed?

Example Jenkinsfile:

```
msBuildPipelinePlugin
{ 
    curl_url = "http://webhook.url.com" 
}
```

custom pipeline groovy code:

def response = sh(script: 'curl -i -X POST -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{"text","Jenkins Info.\nThis is more text"}' curl_url, returnStdout: true)

Thanks

Comment: Is yours a Declarative or a Scripted pipeline and are you looking to provide the URL as a parameter during every build?

Comment: I'm looking to create a groovy curl statement through the custom pipeline and get the url from the jenkinsfile that is used for the build.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it to work using

//response is just the output of the curl statement

def response = ["curl", "-i", "-v", "-X", "POST", "--data-urlencode", "payload={\"text\":\"message body\"}", "curl url goes here"].execute().text

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you want to specify the URL as a string during every build, you can do either of the following:

**Declarative Pipeline**

Use the [`parameters {}`](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#parameters) directive:

```
pipeline {
    agent {
        label 'rhel-7'
    }
    parameters {
        string(
            name: 'CURL_URL',
            defaultValue: 'http://www.google.com',
            description: 'Enter the URL for file download'
        )
    }
    stages {
        stage('download-file') {
            steps {
                echo "The URL is ${params.CURL_URL}"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Scripted Pipeline**

Use the [`properties([parameters([...])])`](https://st-g.de/2016/12/parametrized-jenkins-pipelines) step:

```
parameters([
    string(
        name: 'CURL_URL',
        defaultValue: 'http://www.google.com',
        description: 'Enter the URL for file download'
    )
])
node('rhel-7') {
    stage('download-file') {
        echo "The URL is ${params.CURL_URL}"
    }
}
```

You can choose to leave the values of `defaultValue` and `description` empty.

**Job GUI**

Either of the above syntax will be rendered in the GUI as:

[image]

Comment: Hi, It looks like parameters aren't set in the jenkinsfile from the GUI you gave.  I'm looking to set the CURL_URL in the jenkinsfile as a property.  So have the buildpipeline{ CURL_URL = "http://dummyurl.com" }  and can use the CURL_URL in the groovy statements.

Comment: I am not sure if I understand this correctly. In this example, whatever value of `CURL_URL` you provide through the GUI will persist throughout the lifecycle of the build and can be accessed from the pipeline and in your Groovy statements using `${params.CURL_URL}`. Here `http://www.google.com` is just a placeholder value that you can choose to leave empty or use anything else.

Comment: If this is not the correct understanding, you may provide your code sample to help understand your use case better.